# Pyspark and Mongodb Connector

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

How to connect Pyspark(spark2.2) and Mongodb in Ubuntu?? Please anyone here who can help me? I am not getting any solution !

I was trying from following link:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/spark/src/main/python/README.rst

but can't resolve problem

[I am stuck on last two lines in this image, I don't know how to put mongo-hadoop-spark.jar on Spark's classpath??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2dxv.png)

Comment: Everything was mentioned in that page. Can you ask any specific question when you are trying?

Comment: What code have you tried, what is your error?

Comment: @mrsrinivas sir how can I put mongo-hadoop-spark.jar on spark's CLASSPATH ??